# I am getting a error while using a floating button inside a card view and applying that card inside a recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-theme

Getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cako, PID: 7165
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73 in com.example.cako:layout/layout_for_horizontal_recyclerview: Binary XML file line #73 in com.example.cako:layout/layout_for_horizontal_recyclerview: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73 in com.example.cako:layout/layout_for_horizontal_recyclerview: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.example.cako.RecyclerVview.onCreateViewHolder(FirstActivity.java:72)
        at com.example.cako.RecyclerVview.onCreateViewHolder(FirstActivity.java:58)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:763)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:426)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:247)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1599)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:585)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:763)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:426)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:247)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:213)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:148)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:212)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:201)
            ... 83 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7165 SIG: 9
```

XML code for  layout_for_horizontal_recyclerview.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/CardColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Great"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewForPieceInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewforPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewForPieceInfo" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/cardView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and my FirstActivity.java file which contains recycler view which imlements that card is:

```
package com.example.cako;
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        String []x={"Aaran", "Aaren", "Aarez", "Aarman", "Aaron", "Aaron-James", "Aarron", "Aaryan", "Abhinav","Ankit"};
        String []image= {"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Aloo_gobi.jpg/180px-Aloo_gobi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Aloo_gobi.jpg/180px-Aloo_gobi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Aloo_Tikki_served_with_chutneys.jpg/180px-Aloo_Tikki_served_with_chutneys.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Aloo_Mattar.jpg/180px-Aloo_Mattar.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Aloo_Methi_%28Aaloo_Methi%29.JPG/180px-Aloo_Methi_%28Aaloo_Methi%29.JPG",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Spicy_alloo_with_tadka_mirchi.jpg/180px-Spicy_alloo_with_tadka_mirchi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Aloo_gobi.jpg/180px-Aloo_gobi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Aloo_gobi.jpg/180px-Aloo_gobi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Aloo_Tikki_served_with_chutneys.jpg/180px-Aloo_Tikki_served_with_chutneys.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Aloo_Mattar.jpg/180px-Aloo_Mattar.jpg"
        };

        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar) ;
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        RecyclerView horizontalrecyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHorizontal);
        horizontalrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
        horizontalrecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerVview(getApplicationContext(),x,image));

        RecyclerView verticalrecyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewVertical);
        verticalrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        verticalrecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerVview(getApplicationContext(),x,image));
    }
}

class RecyclerVview extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerVview.Holder>{
    Context co;
    String[] name;
    String[] image;

    public RecyclerVview(Context applicationContext, String[] x, String[] image) {
        co=applicationContext;
        name=x;
        this.image=image;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(co).inflate(R.layout.layout_for_horizontal_recyclerview,parent,false);
        return new Holder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewForItemName.setText(name[position]);
        Glide.with(co).load(image[position]).into(holder.image);
        holder.floatingActionButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(co,"yesWorking",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                return true;
            }
        });
        holder.textViewForPrice.setText("30$");
        holder.textViewForPieceInfo.setText("Single Piece Only.");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return name.length;
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView textViewForItemName;
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
        TextView textViewForPrice;
        TextView textViewForPieceInfo;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textViewForItemName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            floatingActionButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
            textViewForPieceInfo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewForPieceInfo);
            textViewForPrice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewforPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the context used in the Adapter.

> `horizontalrecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerVview(getApplicationContext(),x,image));`
> `verticalrecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerVview(getApplicationContext(),x,image));`

You have to pass in the `Activity`, not an `ApplicationContext`.
The `ApplicationContext` hasn't the app theme.

Comment: Thnq sir error is resolved but not able to change the layout further.Once changed the layout and afterwards when wanted to change the layout it keeps on showing the same card layout that I first applied on card